# Extending the java.base module (adding classes to the java.net package)

Tags: java-platform-module-system

JDK 11 (well 9) no longer allows me to place a new class into the `java.net` package (which is necessary to extend classes existing there to gain access to package-private members).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that this is not possible anyway:

I’ve changed the code a little and built it under JDK 8 (digging out an ancient Debian oldstable system for this), but it then fails at runtime with JRE 8:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.net
```

[Turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36127357/2171120) that it’s not permitted to access JVM “internals”. Not even for [useful, and presumably permittable, extensions with a ready-made API for them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28439229/2171120).

(I’ve had the same job doing this for Android, and, with some use of reflection, it worked there… mostly… so I thought it would work even better in OpenJDK, but… evidently not.)